# Find the best fit (left best inverse) for a given function

Tags: linear-algebra

find the best fit (left best inverse) for the equation:

$$y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 x^2 + \alpha_3 x^3$$

given the data points $(x,y)$:

$(-5,-5002) (-3,-1100) (0,2) (3,570) (5,4780)$

Best left inverse:

- $Ax=b$
- $BAx=Bb$

First I found B using:
$B=(A^T *A)^{-1} *A^T$

$A=[1,-5;1,-3;1,0;1,3;1,5]$  (using Matlab format)

$B=[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2;-0.0735,-0.0441,0,0.0441,0.0735]$

$x=Bb$, where

$x=[\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3]^T$

$b=[-5002,-1100,2,570,4780]^T$

Matlab gave me two values for the $x$ vector:  $[-150.0,792.9412]^T$

Which alpha values do these two $x$ values pertain to??

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please make sure I edited your question properly.

Comment: @Amzoti~ Yes that is correct.  Thank you!  I think I'm asking whether or not the higher order polynomial will regress to the simple y = alpha_0 + alpha_1 x.

Comment: @nbubis~I found a similar problem asked back in April.  One of the answers really helped a lot.  I believe it was 'upside' who answered it.  Working the problem in that way gave me the x vector this is a 4x1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you committed was in taking the a matrix itself. you need to take 1 a1 a1^2 a1^3 and so on for all five rows. Then you will get x as a 4X1 matrix